# Metodo charAt() no me funciona en android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de obtener la cantidad de simbolos, letras mayusculas, minusculas y numero en mi password, pero al momento de usar el `charAt()` android studio me marca esto

> Cannot resolve method '`charAt(int)`' 
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y se marca en rojo, ya intente con un index en tipo `byte` y sigue marcandose en rojo:

Codigo:

```
> for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
>           char  pass = password.charAt(i);
>           String passValue = String.valueOf(pass);
>     }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier duda puedo responderla si no me di a entender.

Comment: chartAt espera un entero y tu le estas pasando un byte, byte i = 0

Comment: Verificaste que lo que contiene **password** es de tipo String

Comment: Formule de nuevo la pregunta, el detalle esta en el mensaje que me arroja android studio, cómo si no reconociera el metodo, igual me paso con el `isEmpty()` y lo cambie por un `length() = 0`. No se si android studio no este correctamente configurado.

Comment: Puedes agregar mas del código, a lo mejor el problema esta más arriba. Otra manera podria ser usando un foreach, asi evitas el uso de charAt

Comment: ¿Pero de que tipo es `password`, es de tipo `String`?

Comment: es importante definas que tipo tiene definido "password", en realidad el problema es que esta variable no es de tipo String.

Comment: Si, ya se definio la variable a tipo string, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Se resolvió creando una variable tipo `String` la cual iguale al valor obtenido y guardado en password.

Código:

```
String passwordFirst = password.getText().toString();
    for (int i = 0; i < passwordFirst.length(); i++){
        pass = passwordFirst.charAt(i);
        String passValue = String.valueOf(pass);
    }
```

De ante mano gracias por la ayuda, me fue muy útil todo.